# Voucher number sequence

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to update the existing number sequence of voucher to new fiscal year number sequence that shows the month in the sequence, I know how to make a number sequence with fiscal year but I am not able to do it for voucher number as I am not able to find voucher edt in the `loadModule` method inside `NumberSeqModuleLedger` class.

Can any body guide me where to find the edt in `loadModule()`? In which class can I add `fiscalyear` parameter type to it?

Answer (score 1):

Voucher number sequence codes are set up in Ledger Journal Names form in General Ledger Setup.

You will have to make the number sequence code first then assign the code to the relevant journal name.

Comment: And suppose if I want to update one of the existing number sequence, how can I find it where its been created in which module and class ?

Comment: It is not created in a class.

Comment: See how to setup number sequences, second part: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242127.aspx

Comment: I mean it must be defined in LoadModule method , how to find that ?

Comment: The link you provided creates a number sequence through wizard but I want to edit existing number sequence.

Comment: Read the second part as mentioned.

Comment: I did the second part as specified in the link , but changes are not applied.

Comment: Modify your question to show what you did (screen shots) and the outcome. Again, I does not expect this requires any code changes, and hence this is off-topic in SO.