# Voucher Number Sequence according to months?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, number-sequence

I want to update existing voucher number sequence to new one that change according to month i.e if the month is feb then number sequence should be like 02-0001. As i have researched and found that number sequence is auto generated from the wizard so i am facing some problem how to update this.

There is a method called **newGetVoucherFromCode** in number seq class that might be used to change the scope of voucher number sequence. The method is as follows :

```
public static NumberSeq newGetVoucherFromCode(
        NumberSequenceCode  _voucherSequenceCode,
        NumberSeqScope      _scope = NumberSeqScopeFactory::createDefaultScope(),
        boolean             _makeDecisionLater           = false,
        boolean             _dontThrowOnMissingRefSetUp  = false,
        //<GEERU><GEEU>
        UnknownNoYes        _allowManual                 = UnknownNoYes::Unknown)
        //</GEERU></GEEU>
{
    return NumberSeq::newGetVoucherFromId(
                NumberSequenceTable::findByNaturalKey(_voucherSequenceCode, _scope.getId()).RecId,
                _makeDecisionLater,
                _dontThrowOnMissingRefSetUp,
                //<GEERU><GEEU>
                _allowManual);
                //</GEERU></GEEU>
}
```

now how can I change its scope to makes it to generate number sequence month wise ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard feature to make a number sequence follow the fiscal year and month.

See here how to do it: [Year in number sequence](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/goshoom/archive/2013/10/16/year-in-number-sequence-ax2012.aspx)

You will have to make a number sequence for each period:

[image: Number sequence form with fiscal period]

In order to use a period number sequence you will have to provide the company and fiscal period.

```
FiscalCalendarPeriod p;
select firstOnly p //This is not the way to find a fiscal period:
    where p.Month == FiscalPeriodMonth::Month1 && 
          p.StartDate == 01\01\2014 && 
          p.Type == FiscalPeriodType::Operating;
info(NumberSeq::newGetNumFromCode('Test', NumberSeqScopeFactory::createDataAreaFiscalCalendarPeriodScope(curext(),p.RecId)).num());
```

You will have to change the voucher number generation in journals to cope with this, which is not going to be an easy job.

Also see [Customize Existing Number Sequence to Fiscal Year Number Sequence](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/thedynamicsblog/archive/2013/12/29/customize-existing-number-sequence-to-fiscal-year-number-sequence.aspx)

Comment: I know how to do it but I am not able to do it for Voucher number, I am not able to find the VOUCHER edt in LoadModule to add the parameter of fiscal year to it.

Comment: As previously told voucher numbers are not defined in `loadModule`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486294/voucher-number-sequence

Comment: I don't need year in it , I just want month in the number sequence, yes I know it is not an easy job to do it for voucher number

Comment: Well, this does not change the answer, you still need a sequence for each and every fiscal period.